# Ошибка с модулем multiprocessing (self._args = tuple(args) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Часть кода, в котором ошибка:

```
def load_process(t):
    pass


def load(t2, process):  # Симулятор загрузки
    timer = t2 / 100  # Вычисляем, сколько времени нужно для полной загрузки
    if process:
        Process(target=load_process, args=t2).start()  # <-- Ошибка в этой строке
```

При запуске `load` выходит ошибка:

```
self._args = tuple(args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Например:
`load(10, True)`

Возможно, ошибка глупая, так как я новичок в этом модуле

Comment: Для импорта использую `from multiprocessing import Process`

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
args=t2
```

В качестве аргументов нужно передавать кортеж (или что-то, что может быть преобразовано питоном в кортеж, как правильно заметил Jack_oS, например, список). Поскольку аргумент у вас один, нужно обязательно ставить запятую, чтобы питон понял, что это именно кортеж, а не просто скобки:

```
args=(t2,)
```

Comment: или `Process(target=load_process, args=[t2]).start()` upd [хотя нет](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions): "args is the argument tuple for the target invocation", кортеж

Comment: @Jack_oS Как-раз если передавать список, запятая, наверное, не нужна, иначе какой смысл передавать список вместо кортежа )

Comment: @Jack_oS Если передать что-то, что может быть преобразовано в кортеж, то всё получится, так что список можно передавать